# UTF-8 in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I add UTF-8 Strings into a JTable? Strings in the ASCII range look ok, but characters that have accents aren't showing up properly.

Comment: Do the UTF-8 strings show up correctly in the rest of your application?

Comment: Yes, if I use System.out.println(string) before adding it to the JTable, it outputs correctly.

Comment: I meant in your Swing application. Try to display some of the accented words to a JLabel or JTextField.

Comment: No, it doesn't work properly in a JTextField. Strangely, this is now only happening when I export it to a JAR, but the characters show up correctly when I run it in Netbeans.

Comment: What happens if you build your jar in Netbeans and run it on your system?

Comment: I'm only running it on my system.

Comment: I'm exporting the JAR using Netbeans when testing the jar.

Comment: Might it have something to do with your font?

Comment: The program opens up a file and displays contents of the file in the JTable. If I copy and paste the characters directly into the source code, it shows up fine. But if I open the contens from the file, the text only shows up correctly when I run the program in Netbeans. The text doesn't show up correctly if I export it to a Jar from Netbeans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was reading in the strings without setting the reader to a UTF-8 encoding.
After changing

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(di));
```

to

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(di, "UTF-8"));
```

the text showed up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Above is a row in JTable (a screenshot) with normal accent characters deliberately inserted into it. The JTable is the usual one without any special modifications to accomodate or accept special characters.

Accent characters as defined in: http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codealt.html

Source code:

```
JTable table = new javax.swing.JTable();
DefaultTableModel model = null;

public void initTableModel() {
    model = new DefaultTableModel();
    table.setModel(model);
    model.addColumn("col1");
    model.addColumn("col2");
    ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
    selectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    ListSelectionModel rowSM = table.getSelectionModel();
    table.removeAll();
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn((model.getColumnCount() - 1)).setPreferredWidth(200); 
}

public void initTableData() {
    int numrows = model.getRowCount();
    for (int i = numrows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        model.removeRow(i);
    }

    String[] row = new String[3];
    if (pass != null) {
            row[0] = "Lü Dongbin呂洞賓Lán Cǎihé";
            row[1] = "《全唐詩》ó, ò, ñ";
            model.addRow(row);
    }
    validate();
    repaint();
}
```

Entire Java source code: http://ahb.me/1exq (More accurate and tested)

Is this the codes you wanted ?